# pass the list as parameters in the batch file

Tags: java, batch-file

I want to pass the list of string as a parameter in the batch file but its not working. Can 
anyone give me the solution.
My code is like this:

```
Process pr = rt.exec(new String[] { "cmd", "/c", "D:/test.bat " + s1.get(i)});
```

But when i fire the command directly without using batch file, it works.

```
Process pr = rt.exec(new String[] { "cmd", "/c", 
     "java -jar D:/clientApplication.jar " + s1.get(i)});
```

sample examples in java preferred.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to pass the whole list or just one of its parameters?

Comment: In the current context, I want to pass the list parameters one by one sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new String[] { "cmd", "/c", "D:/test.bat ", s1.get(i)}
```